# can't get refresh token for google api. Node js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api

I've got an Apps Script script that I am running remotely through Google's API. When I go to the link it gives me for the code to retrieve the access token, it says that the file requested does not exist. However, the code is in the url anyway, this gives me the access token, but not the refresh token.

I have tried adding 'access_type: offline' and 'approval_prompt: force', but those didn't change anything. Here's the code:

```
var { google } = require('googleapis');
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
const readline = require('readline');




// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"

];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('./credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Apps Script API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), callScriptFunction);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  //   const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2("294862899955-bb0929ato2qem8cqllggrpuqpqit191v.apps.googleusercontent.com", "Ds4-q0G3QZog4UamQrc3HFrW", "https://script.google.com/oauthcallback");

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

function callScriptFunction(auth) {
  var scriptId = "MwnuiFwldt-0ZLyLnoi0Q5kfoO49Cn6ao";
  var script = google.script('v1');

  script.scripts.run({
    auth: auth,
    resource: {
      function: 'automateSheet',
      parameters: [
        process.argv[2],
        process.argv[3],
        process.argv[4],
        process.argv[5],
        process.argv[6],
        process.argv[7],
        process.argv[8],
      ]
    },
    scriptId: scriptId,
    devMode: true
  }, function (err, resp) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      var r = resp.data;
      if ("error" in r) {
        console.log("Error: %o", r.error);
      } else {
        console.log("Result: %o", r.response.result);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Here's the page Google gives me when I agree to allow the app access to my account: [image]

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer here:

[Not receiving Google OAuth refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token)

where the guy said to go to  https://myaccount.google.com/u/2/permissions?pli=1&pageId=none

then revoke your apps permission. it worked for me. because every time after the first time, the refresh token does not appear

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues going on. One, it looks like your **Authorized redirect URI** isn't set correctly.  It needs to be set to a page on your server that listens for the **code** URL parameter after the user authorizes. You can set it in the Google Cloud console under API > Credentials > 0Auth Client Settings > Authorized redirect URIs.

Second, I had an issue where sometimes I wouldn't get a refresh token. Turns out I had to add `prompt: 'consent'` to the `generateAuthUrl` request to force it to always return a refresh token, by always taking the user through the full authorization flow (instead of skipping steps if they recently authenticated). So your function would be:

```
const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
    prompt: 'consent',
});
```

Hope that helps. For reference: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/750#issuecomment-368873635